# How do i make my upload work if my function is from another php file

Tags: php

im trying to make my upload work without having the function at the same php but calls it from another php

and it should be like... after submitting an order with an uploaded image
the image file will be sent to my ftp/ photos folder i created but still empty

what seems to be missing :o

shop.php

```
<!--UPLOAD PART -->
    <form action="shop.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select Image: <input type="file" name="image">
</form>
```

then my function

```
    if($activity == "upload"){

     $image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
     $image_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
     $image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
     $image_tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    if($image_name==''){
        echo "<script>alert('Please Select an Image')</script>";
        exit();
    }
    else{
        move_uploaded_file($image_tmp_name,"photos/$image_name");
        echo "Image uploaded successfully";
        echo "<img src='photos/$image_name'>";


    }
}
```

oh and  i got this from a tutorial video
and it works when code is at the same php 
but applying to my current project  well... it doesn't

Comment: You need to chmod the folder to `777`

Comment: What errors do you get? Is the function included in the `shop.php` page at any point? How are you defining the `$activity` variable? Who is going to be using this form? Because it would be very, very simple to upload a malicious file and then execute it on your server, you're not checking that it's an image in any way.

Comment: it doesnt have any errors, its just registers an order and does not upload the image
well i tried including the function at the same code, it doesnt work as well...

Comment: uhh originally this is the code i got from a tutorial... and i want to separate the function from the forms and call it instead from another php

Comment: Issue is likely permissions, I would recommend you use [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) and consider using a component such as [UploadedFile](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File) from Symfony

Answer (score 0):

Your 'function code' is not inside a function. You should first enclose it inside a named function. Perhaps:

```
if(activity == "upload")
{ functionCode(); }
```

After doing that, you should create another php file 'uploadFunction.php' and cut the `functionCode()` into it. Then include `uploadFunction.php` in `shop.php`; At the top of `shop.php`:

```
 <?php include("directory-location\uploadFunction.php"); ?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is what was being asked.